# submit function to run in parallel step on emr

Tags: pyspark, boto3, amazon-emr

I'm submitting steps to run in parallel on an emr.  I'm doing this by saving python scripts with pyspark code at an s3 path.  I then use the boto code below to submit the steps in parallel to the emr.  The steps run the code I have saved to s3 in script files.  I would like to instead create a function, like the "read_write" example function below, to perform the same operations I'm doing in the saved python scripts.  That way I wouldn't have to save a python script file to s3 for every step I'm trying to run in parallel.  Is there a way to submit the code I would like to run in the step to the emr with the boto code below, without having to save it in a script file to s3?  I've supplied example code similar to what I'm currently using to submit steps to run in parallel below.  I've also supplied code similar to what I would like to try to do, creating the "read_write" function in the same code with the boto script and submitting it as a step to run in parallel to the emr.

```
# test1.py

from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

import pyspark

# from cloudwatch_logs import (log_handler, error_manager)

import boto3
#############

#############

conf = pyspark.SparkConf()
spark = SparkSession.builder \
            .appName("test1") \
            .config('spark.sql.codegen.wholeStage', False) \
            .getOrCreate()
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df=sqlContext.read.parquet("path1")

df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("write_path1")


# test2.py

from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

import pyspark

# from cloudwatch_logs import (log_handler, error_manager)

import boto3
#############

#############

conf = pyspark.SparkConf()
spark = SparkSession.builder \
            .appName("test2") \
            .config('spark.sql.codegen.wholeStage', False) \
            .getOrCreate()
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df=sqlContext.read.parquet("path2")

df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("write_path2")








# script to submit multiple steps to run in parallel on emr


client = boto3.client('emr', region_name='us-west-2')
response = client.add_job_flow_steps(
    JobFlowId='j-xxxxxxxx', # clusterid
    Steps=[
        {
            'Name': 'test1',
            'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',
            'HadoopJarStep': {
                'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
                'Args': [
              "spark-submit",
              "--deploy-mode",
              "cluster",
              "--master",
              "yarn",
              "--conf",
              "spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=true",
              "s3a://path/test1.py"

            ]
            }
        },
        {
             'Name': 'test2',
            'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',
            'HadoopJarStep': {
                'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
                'Args': [
              "spark-submit",
              "--deploy-mode",
              "cluster",
              "--master",
              "yarn",
              "--conf",
              "spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=true",
              "s3a://path/test2.py"
            ]
            }
        }
    ]
)






# what I would like to do


from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

import pyspark

# from cloudwatch_logs import (log_handler, error_manager)

import boto3


# function to read and write dataframe

def read_write(read_path,write_path):

    df=sqlContext.read.parquet(read_path)

    df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(write_path)



client = boto3.client('emr', region_name='us-west-2')
response = client.add_job_flow_steps(
    JobFlowId='j-xxxxxxxx', # clusterid
    Steps=[
        {
            'Name': 'test1',
            'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',
            'HadoopJarStep': {
                'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
                'Args': [
              "spark-submit",
              "--deploy-mode",
              "cluster",
              "--master",
              "yarn",
              "--conf",
              "spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=true",
              read_write(read_path='path1',write_path='write_path1')

            ]
            }
        },
        {
             'Name': 'test2',
            'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',
            'HadoopJarStep': {
                'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
                'Args': [
              "spark-submit",
              "--deploy-mode",
              "cluster",
              "--master",
              "yarn",
              "--conf",
              "spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=true",
              read_write(read_path='path2',write_path='write_path2')
            ]
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just turn on the concurrent steps?

> StepConcurrencyLevel (integer) -- Specifies the number of steps that can be executed concurrently. The default value is 1 . The maximum value is 256 .

Check the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.run_job_flow) for more details.

Comment: if I turned the concurrency number up would it run the actions in the same pyspark script in series or in parallel?  so for example if I had multiple write steps for different dataframes would it wait for the first dataframe to finish writing to s3, before it wrote out the second one?  my goal in this example is to get them both to write at the same time, parallel.

Comment: Each step is separated and run in parallel.

Comment: I created two emr.  one of them I turned the stepconcurrency up to 256, the other I left with the default=1.  I ran the same script on both that just read in some data and then wrote it back out again for 4 different large dataframes.  it took the same amount of time on both emr.  when we break this up into 4 different scripts and run them in parallel steps like the example code I have on the ticket, we see the emr finish much quicker.